# MS Project doesn't calculate task finish date correclty

Tags: ms-project, resources, ms-project-2016

I have an issue with MS Project 2016.

I have a task which starts on May 9th and is estimated to 72 hrs. I have assigned a resource, which is available 4 hours per day (I assigned the resource using his own calendar where his availability is set). The task type is **Fixed work** and it's effort driven. The duration is 18 days, and there are just just 3 working days marked as non-working.

And yet, MS Project calculates the finish date to be July 7th (40 working days after May 9th).

I'd appreciate any suggestions as to what may be wrong.

Comment: What are you *expecting* the finish date to be?

Comment: I expect the task to finish on June 1st. 72hr/4 hrs per day = 18 days. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out.

In the respective resource calendar -> work weeks -> details 
the time for the allocated resource was set to:

08:00 AM - 10:00 AM 
11:AM - 1:00 PM

I changed that to:

08:00 AM - 10:00 AM 
1:00 PM - 3:PM

And project recalculated the duration correctly.

I have no idea what was wrong with the time which was set initially.

Comment: have you test it ? i have the same oroblem